# Remove photoswipe-css and photoswipe-default-skin-css in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am building a custom webshop and I am trying to remove the photoswipe style documents but I can't seem to get rid of them, I tried a couple of "solutions" that I found online but they are not working. This is what I tried so far in the functions.php:

```
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
```

and

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'wpf_dequeue_styles' );
function wpf_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
unset( $enqueue_styles['photoswipe-css'] );
unset( $enqueue_styles['photoswipe-default-skin-css'] );
return $enqueue_styles;
}
```

and

```
wp_dequeue_script('photoswipe-css');
wp_dequeue_script('photoswipe-default-skin-css');
```

Can someone help me finding the solution? I don't have any images in my webshop so I do not need these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can `remove_theme_support` using `after_setup_theme` action hook.

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_photoswipe_css', 11 ); 
function remove_photoswipe_css() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-slider' );
}
```

You can `wp_dequeue_style` using `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook.

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_photoswipe_css', 11 );
function dequeue_photoswipe_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'photoswipe' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'photoswipe-default-skin' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for the answer to this then the correct code would be :

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_photoswipe_css', 99);
function dequeue_photoswipe_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'photoswipe' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'photoswipe-default-skin-css' );
    wp_dequeue_script( 'photoswipe-ui-default' );
}
```